Display periodically turns on during screen lock
I have a Nokia G22 with Android 13. I noticed that during screen lock sometimes my phone turns the display on and off periodically in a few seconds. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Does your power button works flawless? One possible reason for such a behavior could be an excessively sensible power button which already triggers by hatching it or even just moving the phone.

I don't think so. The "power / turn dispay on" is placed deeply in the case. I noticed this strange behavior when my phone was in a mobile phone holder in the car, so the power button was surely untouched.

If the phone was in a car and you were moving the whole car and of course the phone will shake a little bit. May there is something loose in the phone causing the power button or something else to trigger?

The phone is in a phone holder, so the power button is safe. However, this behaviour doesn't appear always, sometimes the phone is idle as expected. I have to figure out why. Thank you for guiding.
